# Does the sentence "what do you like to do?" have a direct object?

Tags: syntax

In japanese the sentence "what do you like to do?" has the word ***what*** succeeded by the particle "o" which marks direct objects, meaning for japaneses "what" is the direct object of this sentence. Is this the same in english? Yes/No - Why?

Comment: Pardon me but I didn't get you!

Comment: Which is the direct object of "what do you like to do?" in english? Is "what" just like in japanese?

Comment: Yes, 'what' can be analyzed as a direct object. Read [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement) for more info.

Comment: I assume you mean the Japanese "what do you *want* to do?" and not "what do you *like* to do?"   The Japanese for "to like" does not take the particle "wo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a question, the direct object may be the *interrogative pronoun* **what**, **which**, or **whom**. It cannot be **where**, **how**, or **when**. They are adverbs. Sometimes it helps to keep all the words in the sentence and turn it into a declarative sentence. ([**English Grammar 101**](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-4/sentence-parts/lesson-7/challenges-with-direct-objects))

- **What** do you like to do? - You like to do **what**. *(The direct object is **what**)*

Comment: Notice that I'm not sure why they say "**which**" is an interrogative pronoun, when actually I doubt it is one.